Movie about a haunted couple at their honeymoon in a cabin
I watched a horror movie about 4~5 years ago that it was a story about newly married couple who would spend their honeymoon in a remote house/cabin. Then strange things start to happen. They hear the bell and it was a strange child seems to be lost. They dismiss the child, but it come back again. So the man left the house for some reason and the children start to scare the woman. At the end the haunting becomes more frequent and the children enters the house. The couple tries to run away but the car doesn't works. 
I don't remember much more.
Anyone knows the name of this movie??

I've found it.
The Strangers @ IMDB
I assume that's have nothing to do with marriage or haunting haha
There goes the synopsis taken from here:

Kristen McKay (Liv Tyler) and James Hoyt (Scott Speedman) return to
  the remote summer vacation home owned by James's parents in the
  mid-hours of the night following a friend's wedding reception. After
  an episode between the couple when Kristen turns down a marriage
  proposal from James, they receive a knock at the front door from a
  blonde woman. "Is Tamara home?", she asks. "No, I think you have the
  wrong house", they tell her. The mysterious woman then walks off into
  the night. James leaves the house to go buy cigarettes and get his
  mind off of things. Meanwhile, Kristen stays at the house alone. The
  blonde woman returns, asking for Tamara, but this time Kristen does
  not open the door; "You already came by here", she tells the woman,
  who responds with "Are you sure?". The smoke alarm goes off soon
  after, due to the fireplace being blocked, and Kristen pulls the alarm
  off the ceiling and it clatters to the floor. Someone begins banging
  at the door. Kristen, a little unnerved at the entire situation, locks
  the doors in the house, and calls James asking him to hurry back, when
  the phone line goes dead. Kristen plugs her cell phone in to charge
  it, changes into jeans and a flannel shirt, and then picks up a
  half-smoked cigarette. As she stands in the living room of the house,
  a man wearing a sack mask emerges from the hallway behind her, and
  watches her silently as she gets a glass of water. He then disappears.
Another barrage of knocks come from the front door, and Kristen sees
  the smoke alarm, which was previously lying on the floor, sitting
  neatly on the center of a dining room chair. She hurries to grab her
  cell phone, but it has been taken off the charger and is nowhere in
  sight. She hears something hitting the windchimes and making a
  dragging noise on the back patio, and she slowly, armed with a kitchen
  knife, walks toward the sliding glass door. She pulls the curtain
  back, and the man in the mask is standing there, and he slams his hand
  on the window. She screams in terror, and bumps into the phonograph in
  the living room, knocking the needle off track, which causes it to
  begin repeating the same phrase from a country song. Suddenly, the
  front door opens slightly, and Kristen approaches it. In between the
  crack of the door someone wearing a doll-like mask peeks her head
  through. Kristen closes the door, locks it, and hides in the bedroom,
  yelling for the strangers to go away. Suddenly, the vinyl album stops
  skipping, and footsteps come down the hallfortunately, it is only
  James, who is entirely unaware of what is going on.
The couple search the house, but find nobody, and James initially
  believes Kristen to be letting her imagination get to her. The couple
  see the blonde woman, Dollface (Gemma Ward), standing in the back
  yard, staring at the house. James then goes outside to the car to
  retrieve his cell phone, only to find the car entirely vandalized, and
  his cell phone stolen. Dollface touches the back of his neck as he is
  crouched down in the car, and runs off, only to reappear a few feet
  from the car. He tells her to leave, and Kristen pokes her head
  outside in concern. James turns to Kristen, and when he turns back
  around, Dollface has vanished. James returns to the house, and he and
  Kristen find his cell phone sitting on the piano with its battery
  removed. James decides it's time to leave.
They go outside and attempt to drive away in the car, even with its
  tires slashed, but a truck pulls up behind them, driven by a different
  unidentified woman, wearing a mask that resembles a pin up. The Man in
  the Mask (Kip Weeks) appears in front of the car, and the Pin Up
  Girl(Laura Margolis) rear-ends the car, as James and Kristen scramble
  back into the house. They find a shotgun and gun shells in the
  bedroom, along with the word "hello" written all over the bedroom
  window in red paint by the villains. They approach the front door with
  the gun, and the Man in the Mask begins to break through the door with
  an axe. They block the door with the piano, and James attempts to
  shoot him, but misses. They then hide in a room down the hallway,
  armed with the gun toward the open doorway.
James' friend, Mike (Glenn Howerton), whom he called earlier, arrives
  at the house, and has a rock thrown through his windshield. He
  approaches the house, and hears country music playing loudly on the
  record player. He enters through the back glass door, just as Dollface
  emerges from the shadows behind him. He sees the house is a complete
  disaster, and he walks down the hallway as the music continues
  playing. The Man in the Mask appears behind him, holding up his axe
  preparing to strike. Just as the music stops, Mike steps in the
  doorway, and James fires the gun, striking Mike right in the head. He
  dies instantly, and after a few seconds James and Kristen realize they
  shot the wrong person. The villains paint "KILLER" on the back door to
  taunt James, and he heads to the barn outside to use a ham radio for
  help. He spots Pin Up Girl emerging from the barn, and attempts to
  shoot at her from down on the ground, but the Man in the Mask runs up
  behind him at full speed. Kristen soon follows, after she senses the
  presence of the Man in the Mask in the house. She falls, twists her
  ankle, and is unknowingly stalked through the front lawn by Pin Up
  Girl. Once she gets to the barn, she fiddles with the radio, but it is
  then destroyed by Pin Up Girl.
Kristen crawls back to the house, as Dollface sits on the swing set in
  the backyard and Pin Up Girl stands in front of the barn. Once inside,
  Kristen cannot find James, and the power goes out. The Man in the Mask
  then enters the front door, and Kristen hides in a pantry as he lurks
  around the living room. He leaves, and just as Kristen is about to
  slip out of the pantry, Dollface appears in the door's slit shutters,
  and smashes it through. She then pauses, and notices the engagement
  ring, and Kristen emerges from the pantry, while Dollface taunts her
  by spinning a butcher knife around on the counter. The Man in the Mask
  then enters the house, holding a defeated James by his shirt collar.
  Kristen runs to the bedroom, but the window does not open. The lights
  come back on, and she creeps back toward the hallway. Upon reaching
  the doorway, The Man in the Mask rushes toward her, slamming her head
  into the back wall of the hallway. She falls to the floor and he drags
  her down the hall. She is initially unconscious but soon begins to
  claw at the floor and the screen fades to black as she screams.
It is then daylight, and each of the strangers loom over Kristen and
  James, who are now tied to chairs in the living room; Kristen has been
  dressed back into her white gown. Kristen cries, and asks "Why are you
  doing this to us?", to which Dollface emotionlessly replies, "Because
  you were home". Each villain removes their mask, but the camera does
  not show their faces. The three strangers then take turns stabbing
  James and Kristen, and then leave in their truck. As they drive down
  the road, they stop to talk to two boys delivering religious
  pamphlets. Dollface gets out of the truck and asks for one, to which
  one of the boys asks, "Are you a sinner?". "Sometimes", she says, and
  when the children are out of ear shot, Pin Up Girl says quietly,
  "It'll be easier next time." The strangers then drive off.
The two boys approach the house, and enter to find a bloody and
  disastrous scene. James lies on the floor, dead, and Kristen in the
  hallway, her white gown saturated in blood. One of the boys approaches
  Kristen's body, and just as he is about to reach toward her, she grabs
  his arm and screams in terror.


I've actually been searching for this movie because it was the first thing that came up in my mind... Although I've seen only a bit of it.

Bear in mind that The Strangers is a remake of 'Ils' (They) which is a French film that actually fits your description a lot better. In Ils, the antagonists ARE children, this was changed for the US remake. Ils is a far better film too.

@Nobby Thank you for this information, I'll look for this movie!!

Yes. there are no children in "The Strangers" and the couple isn't on a honeymoon either.

There is a movie called Shutter (2008, USA) about a newly-wed couple. There is also a 2004 Thai movie with this name, of which the 2008 one is a remake of; however according to IMDB they're not married in this one.

Shutter is a bad guess i think.

I've only seen a bit of it but it sounds like it could very well be the one... Aw well we'll see if it's a right guess or not :)

Nope, it haves nothing to do with photographs or accidents.

There are no children in Shutter. It's a completely different story.
